# load flash inside of iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, flash

I have one site, written in php and inside of the .php site there are a lot of swf (flash)
files, I want to load my php site inside of my iPad application,just read the address of php site and load it on safari, I can load my php site inside of my UIWebView, but I cann"t see the flash part,

Would you please give me some hints to fixed my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh, you can't use Flash.

Comment: Yeah.. I thought ipod, iphones and ipads couldn't use flash.. Get an android based piece of hardware. ;)

Comment: The problem with iOS development is that even people who don't even know the basic capabilities of their device (since 6 years!) are trying to make The World's Best iOS App Ever (TM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to disappoint you: iOS doesn't have capabilities to play Flash.

For jailbroken devices, there's [Frash](http://github.com/comex/frash) - you can get some ideas from it.

Comment: what should I use instead of flash?

Comment: @ghazal modern standard web technologies. HTML5, CSS3 and their corresponding JavaScript-bindings.

Comment: Be prepared for some serious pain if you try to emulate Flash in Canvas/JS (my job has involved a lot of this for the last three months, purely because of this bit of greed/control-freakery on Apple's part) - even with Create.JS, it's like going back ten years, JS is pathetic next to AS3 if you're making anything complex, until Edge comes along we're stuck for a decent IDE for animations and graphics, and it's pushing it a bit to call any of the above 'standard' just yet.

Comment: @MickMalone1983 I'm not saying exactly that Flash should be emulated, in fact, neither does Frash do that, neither do I encourage it.

Comment: I'm not saying you were, it's more a warning for him, a lot of people assume Steve Jobs knew the first thing about dev and wasn't just after app store cash, expect HTML5 dev to be as quick and powerful as Flash and get a nasty surprise. If you go in understanding that it's got a lot of catching up to do, it won't be such a nasty shock!

Comment: @MickMalone1983 Yes, of course - as always, if you think, you won't be surprised, if yon don't, you will :)

Comment: I like that motto very much :)